# An iframe inside of a span which must be display:inline-block;

Tags: html, css

I have to use an inline-block span as that is the only way that I can format text for an older version of Telerik RadTreeView.Net2 and I need to use an iframe as there is quite a bit of underlying logic and formatting in my subpage snippet. I cannot get the scrolling to work no matter what I seem to do. I have tried all variations on overflow combinations for both parent SPAN and child iframe. I am not sure if there is another path to take but any suggestions would be appreciated.  In the html below I only have control over the SPAN and the iframe and not the parent div, corresponding img or the span where class="TreeNode".

```
<div id="cRadTree_t1_t0"><img src="javascript:false" alt="" style="display:none;" class="4" /><img src="javascript:false" id="cRadTree_t1_t0c" alt="" style="display:none;cursor:pointer;" class="2" />
<span class="TreeNode">

<SPAN style="display:inline-block;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:middle;
            width:400px;height:100px;
            padding:0px;
            border:0px;
            overflow-y:scroll"
            >
<iframe style="height:100px;width:100%;padding:0px;overflow-y:hidden;"
src="../../Folder/Page.aspx?Ref=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
</iframe>
</SPAN>

</span></div>
```

Comment: Can't you change your `span`s for `div`s?

Comment: can't.  Doesn't work. Puts the element below the img which makes it look stupid.